How do I use RotaryEncoder and other templated sensor types in pydrake?
I'm getting an import error when I try to import RotaryEncoders or RotaryEncoders_ from pydrake.all or pydrake.systems.sensors. I feel like there's something obvious that I'm missing; all the templated sensor types are "missing" from sensors.pyi. What am I missing?
It's clearly doable, I just must be doing something wrong, c.f. this test: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/03890722e4576c043192303a8270fd1bdf343653/bindings/pydrake/systems/test/sensors_test.py#L579
My setup
I suspect it doesn't matter, but I have pydrake version 1.30.0 installed via pip in a venv on Ubuntu 22.04
What I did
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pydrake.all import RotaryEncoders
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'RotaryEncoders' from 'pydrake.all' (/opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/all.py)
>>> from pydrake.systems.sensors import RotaryEncoders
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'RotaryEncoders' from 'pydrake.systems.sensors' (/opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/systems/sensors.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
>>> from pydrake.systems.sensors import RotaryEncoders_
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'RotaryEncoders_' from 'pydrake.systems.sensors' (/opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/systems/sensors.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

What I expected
To not get an import error

Actually, the drake version does matter. I only very recently PR'd the python bindings for the RotaryEncoders class. They are not in v1.30.0, but will appear in v1.31.0, and are available now in the nightly pip wheels.

Thanks for the quick and clear response!
